# Esper - pattern detection

Tags: sequence, complex-event-processing, esper

I have a question for the community regarding pattern detection with Esper.

Suppose you want to detect the following pattern among a collection of data : A B C

However, it is possible, that in the actual data, you might have: A,B,D,E,C. My goal is to design a rule that could still detect A B C by keeping A B in memory, and fire the alert as soon as it sees C.

Is it possible to do this? With the standard select * from pattern(a = event -> b= event -> c=event), It only outputs when the three are in sequence in the data, but not when there are other useless data between them

Comment: And why is Drools among the tags?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

With the standard "select * from pattern [a=A -> b=B]" there can be any events between A and B. Your statement is therefore wrong. I think you are confused about how to remove useless data. Use a filter such as "a=event(...not useless...) -> b=event(...not useless...)". Within the parens place the filter expressions that distinguish between useless and not useless events, i.e. "a=event(amount>10)" or whatever.

Comment: I tried an example on : http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html     Here are four events that you can copy in the "Advance Time and Send Events" field: StockTick={symbol='GE', price=20.5}

StockTick={symbol='YHOO', price=65}

StockTick={symbol='alpha', price=10.5}

StockTick={symbol='beta', price=12.5}

Comment: And here is the query that you can write in the EPL module text field :             create schema StockTick(symbol string, price double);

select * from pattern[a= StockTick -> b= StockTick] where a.price=20.5 and b.price=10.5

Comment: Unfortunately, this query doesn't output anything even if there are two events that match the EPL rule :(  @user3613754

Comment: The filter expressions don't go into the where clause. Each filter expression is right part of the pattern. Like so: select * from pattern[a= StockTick(price=20.5) -> b= StockTick(price=10.5)]